# center an image with a link on it

Tags: css, image, wordpress, editor, center

Is it possible to center an image only trough setting a class to the `img` tag without side effects? The problem is the following: I have an anchor around an image. If I use the following CSS

```
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And this (stripped down) HTML:

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="fancybox" title="System">
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" title="System" class="aligncenter">
</a>
```

the link takes the whole width of the main div. This means not only the image is clickable - also the space around the image (actually the whole width) is clickable. This is through the CSS `display: block`.
[image]

How can I center an image without using a parent div? I don't want the whole area clickable.

Background:
You can read [this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50638/center-image-aligncenter). It is about Wordpress and the built in editor. He automatically generates the class `aligncenter` on an image (if the user pressed the center button). I need this for my own theme. According to the moderators there this should be only a CSS question and doesn't have to do with changing code in Wordpress.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Second answer:
paste this in `functions.php`

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_class',10,8);
function give_linked_images_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ) {
    // only do this on center
    if($align == 'center') {
        $html = str_replace('aligncenter', '', $html);
        $html = '<p style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" >'.$html.'</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Down side, this won't effect already inserted images...
Also if you can please move the style of the `<p>` to the stylesheet.

Comment: That didn't worked for me. Currently, I could use the style for the class `fancybox` but I don't know which side-effects on other links that would have.

Comment: try adding to the `a style` `float:left`

Comment: If I use your code the image is centered but I still have the clickable areas around the image.

Comment: Ahh you don't want that... just a sec

Comment: Yeah, I know ... I think I can't solve the problem without changing some Wordpress code. But I want to know how a theme developer handle this situation normally.

Comment: See my new answer, just paste it in `functions.php`

Comment: That is a solution I'm talking about! Questions: When does the replacement takes place? When I insert a new image? Because for existing pictures it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: It only takes effect when inserting the image and directly choosing "centered". Later changes aren't affected by this code. Are there more events like `image_send_to_editor`?

Comment: I didn't found anything similar. `the_editor_content` brings me some errors that the parameters where found. How do you know which parameters are available?

Comment: Check the where the `do_action` is called

Answer (score 7):

in aligncenter class add text-align:center

```
.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That didn't change something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with wordpress, but you might want to try setting the image's and the anchors's css 'display' property to 'inline-block'.

If you are limited in changing the document's DOM, another option is adding an 'onClick' attribute to the image.
This will allow you to run some function once the image is clicked.
So, for example, if you want to redirect to another page:

```
<img src='myImg.png' onclick='myRedirect()' style='cursor:pointer'/>
```

And in the page's header:

```
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
    var myRedirect = function(){
        window.location.href = 'Some other location';
    }
</script>
```

Notice the `style='cursor:pointer'`, which changes the mouse's cursor to a 'hand' cursor.

Comment: You want to answer this question by using javascript but it can be done with just css. And an `<a>` tag, meant for links as you know.

Comment: The link is only for using fancybox (for a full version of the thumbnail image). Don't know how your code would look like in this case. The next thing is how I attach the onclick event? Again with JS?

Comment: @janw, Possibly, but since the original question poster wasn't able to solve it with html+css (again, it's probably possible), I suggested this solution.

Comment: Also you answer doesn't center anything

Comment: @janw, read the original post and see that the problem is not with centering the image, but with preventing the area around it from being clickable.

Comment: @testing, sorry - I didn't see that you want to use 'fancybox', I thought you wanted to do redirection.

Comment: @E.Ar: Don't bother! Ideas about different solutions are welcome (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an additional `div` container or even JavaScript, you can make the anchor display as a block:

`.logo {display: block; height: 115px; margin: 0 auto; width: 115px;}`

`/* height and width must equal your image's values */`

`<a href="#" class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>`

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/performancecode/Ggk8v/

Answer (score 1):

it still incorporates a div, but the way i do it is:

```
<div class="megaman">
<a href="img/megaman.jpg"><img src="img/megaman.jpg" alt="megaman"></a>
</div>



img {
height: 125px;
width: 200px;
}

.megaman{
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

And yes, I replaced .logo with .megaman because megaman rocks! But it should work.  I couldn't figure it out without using a div.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found. Adding `/></a>` and width and height to the anchor tag cuts down the hyperlink to the image...

```
<a class="link" href="URL" target="_blank"> <img width="75px" height="75px" alt="Facebook" src="IMAGE LOCATION"/></a>
```